# Number of ways to move from Point 1 to Point 2 in a co-ordinate 2D plain

Tags: algorithm, optimization, recursion, coordinate-systems

I came across a question where it was asked to find the number of unique ways of reaching from point 1 to point 2 in a 2D co-ordinate plain.

Note: This can be assumed without loss of generality that `x1 < x2` and `y1 < y2`.

Moreover the motions are constrained int he following manner. One can move only right or up. means a valid move is from `(xa, ya)` to `(xb, yb)` if `xa < xb` and `ya < yb`.

Mathematically, this can be found by `( [(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)]! ) / [(x2-x1)!] * [(y2-y1)!]`. I have thought of code too.

I have approaches where I coded with dynamic programming and my approach takes around `O([max(x2,y2)]^2)` time and `Theta( x2 * y2 )` where I can just manage with the upper or lower triangular matrix.

Can you think of some other approaches where running time is less than this? I am thinking of a recursive solution where the minimum running time is `O(max(x2,y2))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to write the article to describe this question in detail and complete the answer as well. Here is the link for the same. http://techieme.in/dynamic-programming-distinct-paths-between-two-points/

Answer (score 1):

A simple efficient solution is the mathematical one.

Let `x2-x1 = n` and `y2-y1 = m`.

You need to take exactly `n` steps to the right, and `m` steps up, all is left to determine is their order.

This can be modeled as number of binary vectors with `n+m` elements with exactly `n` elements set to 1.

Thus, the total number of possibilities is `chose(n,n+m) = (n+m)! / (n! * m!)`, which is exactly what you got.

Given that the mathematical answer is both proven and both faster to calculate - I see no reason for using a different solution with these restrictions.

If you are eager to use recursion here, the [recursive formula for binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula) will probably be a good fit here.

**EDIT:**
You might be looking for the [multiplicative formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula) to calculate it.

Comment: I know of this, I have already mentioned this above. Please see the complete question. I want a program which can derive this count in another logical manner.  Well I need another solution because I was asked that way in an interview dude.

Comment: But you can move by 1 unit, 0.1 units.. So you can't know how many moves you need, they are unlimited..

Comment: @BlackBear: I don't follow. One can derive from the question that you can move exactly 1 step each turn, to one of right/left.

Answer (score 0):

To compute the answer, you can use this formula:

`(n+m)!/(n!m!)=(n+1)*(n+2)/2*(n+3)/3*…*(n+m)/m`

So the pseudo code is:

```
let foo(n,m) =
  ans=1;
  for i = 1 to m do
    ans = ans*(n+i)/i;
  done;
  ans
```

The order of multiplications and divisions is important, if you modify it you can have an overflow even if the result is not so large.

Answer (score -2):

try this formula:

```
ans = (x2-x1) * (y2-y1) + 1;
```

Comment: Please, describe your answer and explain why it should solve the problem